# How can I get the last measures rowwise for each patient

Tags: r, dataframe

With this dataset I want to get the last observation available for each individual

```
ID <- c(1:5)
Age <- c(23,34,26,18,35)
day1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,4,2)
day2 <- c(NA,3,NA,NA,NA)
day3 <- c(2,NA,3,NA,4)
last_value <- c(2,3,3,4,4)

mydata <- data.frame(ID, Age, day1, day2, day3)

   ID  Age day1 day2 day3 last_value
1   1   23   NA   NA    2          2
2   2   34   NA    3   NA          3
3   3   26   NA   NA    3          3
4   4   18    4   NA   NA          4
5   5   35    2   NA    4          4
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'get the last observation available'? What is the output that you want to see, and approximately which input do you want to provide to get that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can `select()` those columns you need, `rev()` to arrange them in reverse order, and then `coalesce()` to find the first non-missing element for each row.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(last_value = coalesce(!!!rev(select(., starts_with("day")))))

  ID Age day1 day2 day3 last_value
1  1  23   NA   NA    2          2
2  2  34   NA    3   NA          3
3  3  26   NA   NA    3          3
4  4  18    4   NA   NA          4
5  5  35    2   NA    4          4
```

Also with `across` + `do.call`:

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(last_value = do.call(coalesce, rev(across(starts_with("day")))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, Age)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate(last_value = last(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 5 × 6
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID   Age last_value  day3  day2  day1
  <int> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    23          2     2    NA    NA
2     2    34          3    NA     3    NA
3     3    26          3     3    NA    NA
4     4    18          4    NA    NA     4
5     5    35          4     4    NA     2
```

Comment: You can add `values_drop_na = T` in `pivot_longer` to save you the use of `drop_na()`, and add `names_sort = T` in `pivot_wider` to have the column names sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
mydata$last_value <- apply(mydata[-(1:2)], 1, \(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))
```

-output

```
> mydata
  ID Age day1 day2 day3 last_value
1  1  23   NA   NA    2          2
2  2  34   NA    3   NA          3
3  3  26   NA   NA    3          3
4  4  18    4   NA   NA          4
5  5  35    2   NA    4          4
```

---

Or using `exec` + `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(last_value = exec(coalesce, !!! rlang::syms(names(.)[5:3])))
```